# Why don't async methods in identity services in ASP.NET Core have a parameter for CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

My question is why `async` methods like  `userManager.FindByNameAsync(username)` in identity Services in Asp.Net Core do not have a parameter for `CancellationToken`?
I know it has a property with `CancellationToken.None` value and pass to Entityframework methods but it never sets a value and it`s read only and I cannot set a value for that
What are the solutions for this problem?
[image: This is Identity UserManage service]

When I want to override `CancellationToken` in My custom service which  inherited from `userManager`

[image: iherited]

Comment: My guess would be they are not supposed to be cancelled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor - and why they use virtual ?

Comment: So they can be overridden in a derived class. But default is to have no cancelling. You have to actively support it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor i tried to override it but it is read only and can`t set new value for that

Comment: No, no. Not _set_ it but override it. In a class that derives from UserManager. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual

Comment: i know what you saying i edited the question https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor

Comment: I see the image ( btw don't do that. add code as text, always). You override but refer to the base CancellationToken. Which is `None` ... so you gained nothing from that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor it doesnot work the error is `The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item`

Comment: short answer: protected override CancellationToken  CancellationToken {get; set;} long answer understand what override keyword does in C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3898495/silenttremor thank you for your comment I know how override keyword does but with above code it has error  = cannot override because `CancellationToken` does not have an overridable set accessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer **is by design because value cannot change**.
Related to the needs, custom implementation of [UserManager.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b9efadc59ddbf6743775244622fb95301dd1846c/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs) or at least specific methods needed may be a solution, if not `HttpContext.RequestAborted` is the only cancellation token stopping UserManager async invocations.

Long answer, value of an immutable property won't change, the only way in can change the value is in the constructor of base/abstract class.
Overwritten value of a virtual property is in the driven class same rule apply, meaning all the time there are two values, one in base one in driven. Even if property is mutable, referring from driven at base.whatever when explicitly assigned something will change base value.

Example:

```
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class MyBase
    {
        public MyBase()
        {
        }

        public MyBase(int immutableInt)
        {
            ImmutableInt = immutableInt;
        }

        protected virtual int ImmutableInt { get; } = -1;
        protected virtual int MutableInt { get; set; } = -1;
    }


    public class MyDriven : MyBase
    {
        public MyDriven()
        {
        }

        public MyDriven(int value)
        {
            ImmutableInt = value;
            MutableInt = value;
        }

        public MyDriven(int immutableInt, int mutableInt1): base(immutableInt)
        {
            ImmutableInt = immutableInt;
            MutableInt = mutableInt1;
        }


        protected override int ImmutableInt { get; }
        protected override int MutableInt => base.MutableInt;

        public int ImmutableIntReadonly => ImmutableInt;
        public int BaseImmutableIntReadonly => base.ImmutableInt;

        public int MutableIntReadonly => MutableInt;
        public int BaseMutableIntReadonly => base.MutableInt;

    }

    public class ImmutableTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestImutableOverride()
        {
            MyDriven imutable = new MyDriven(1);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutable.ImmutableIntReadonly);
            Assert.Equal(-1, imutable.BaseImmutableIntReadonly);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutable.MutableIntReadonly);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutable.BaseMutableIntReadonly);


            MyDriven imutableCtor = new MyDriven(1, 1);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutableCtor.ImmutableIntReadonly);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutableCtor.BaseImmutableIntReadonly);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutableCtor.MutableIntReadonly);
            Assert.Equal(1, imutableCtor.BaseMutableIntReadonly);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> it never sets a value and it`s read only and I cannot set a value for
> that What are the solutions for this problem

Check the codes [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/AspNetUserManager.cs)

```
public class AspNetUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser>, IDisposable where TUser : class
{
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance of <see cref="AspNetUserManager{TUser}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="store">The persistence store the manager will operate over.</param>
    /// <param name="optionsAccessor">The accessor used to access the <see cref="IdentityOptions"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="passwordHasher">The password hashing implementation to use when saving passwords.</param>
    /// <param name="userValidators">A collection of <see cref="IUserValidator{TUser}"/> to validate users against.</param>
    /// <param name="passwordValidators">A collection of <see cref="IPasswordValidator{TUser}"/> to validate passwords against.</param>
    /// <param name="keyNormalizer">The <see cref="ILookupNormalizer"/> to use when generating index keys for users.</param>
    /// <param name="errors">The <see cref="IdentityErrorDescriber"/> used to provider error messages.</param>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> used to resolve services.</param>
    /// <param name="logger">The logger used to log messages, warnings and errors.</param>
    public AspNetUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        IServiceProvider services,
        ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
        _cancel = services?.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.RequestAborted ?? CancellationToken.None;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The cancellation token associated with the current HttpContext.RequestAborted or CancellationToken.None if unavailable.
    /// </summary>
    protected override CancellationToken CancellationToken => _cancel;
}
```

You could try

```
protected override CancellationToken CancellationToken => _cancel;
 private CancellationToken _cancel { get; set; }
```

in your target method:

```
public   async  Task<IdentityResult> AsyncMethod(IdentityUser user,CancellationToken token)
    {
        _cancel = token;
       ....;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for response , i tried your code and write a method that return base.CancellationToken value it returns false but in my action cancellationToken is true

Comment: base means UserManager, base. CancellationToken should be CancellationToken.None

Comment: please show your codes and explain your requirement...

Comment: yes because that cancellationToken is passed to Identity Methods

Comment: `public async Task OnGetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken = new CancellationToken(true);
            await userManger.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User, cancellationToken);
            var baseCancellationToken = userManger.GetCancellationToken();

        }`

Comment: // _cancel == true   ;  base.CanellationToken == false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/18177989/ruikai-feng but i want to change cancellationToken in base class , beacause all async methods are there